# How to link a foreign key in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have added a looging table to my asp.net mvc 5 application.

I am using code first migrations for the database. Here is the current ERD.

[image]

Now i want to add the red link to the db so that I can retrieve information about a suer from a log.

Here is my current model for an activity log:

```
 [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Id of the user
    [Required]     
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    //Time of the log
    [Required]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public LogAction Action { get; set; }

    //Ip address of the server submitting the log
    public string ServerIp { get; set; }

    //Message along with the log
    public string message { get; set; }
```

Comment: Change `public string UserId { get; set; }` to `public virtual User User { get; set; }` and `Update-Database`.

Answer (score 3):

For adding the UserId as a foreign key to the UserActivityLogs table, use the following code in your UserActivityLogs table:

```
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]      
    public virtual AspNetUsers User { get; set; }
```

Comment: Where is the AspNetUsers class come from?

Comment: AspNetUsers is the name of the table in db that the user created. Please refer to the ER diagram shown above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this resource - [Define a Foreign Key Constraint in Entity Framework Code First](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319366/EF-Code-First-Add-a-Foreign-Key-relationship)